# Is there a keyboard shortcut to open a mounted TrueCrypt container?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, truecrypt, autohotkey

**Problem**

I would like to open a mounted TrueCrypt container with a keyboard shortcut.

[image]

Currently, I'm opening it by double-clicking the volume. See screenshot above. Instead of using the mouse, I'd like to use the keyboard. But there seems to be no way.

**Versions**

- TrueCrypt 7.1.a
- Windows 7 64bit

**Failed attempts**

- When you right-click on the volume, there is a "Open" command in the context menu. [image]So, I've tried to open the context menu with the <kbd>context
  menu</kbd> key on the Windows keyboard. But strangely enough that does not open the
  context menu.
- I've also tried <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd> to open the context menu, but that does not work either.
- There is no "Open" command in the menues (Volume, System, Favorites, Tools, Settings, Help), so I can't press for instance <kbd>Alt+V</kbd> to open a menu and go from there.
- I tried to [use AutoHotKey to send a double-click command](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm), but that does not work because the double-click is sent to the current mouse position and not the current selection, which would my selected TrueCrypt volume.
- There would be a HotKeys dialog in menu Settings > Hot Keys... But there seems to be no way, to add or configure a hotkey for "Open".

**Workaround**

My current workaround is to tick "Open Explorer window for successfully  mounted volume" in the menu Settings > Preferences...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a shortcut to the TrueCrypt executable and append the appropriate command-line arguments (such as /volume /password /explore), or create a shortcut to a batch file with the appropriate commands? This will allow you to set up a keyboard shortcut to mount the volume as well as open an Explorer window if the mount operation was successful.

See detailed command-line option listing for TrueCrypt [here](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=command-line-usage).